# Create modules Java

Tags: java

I have a Java bot running based on the PircBotX framework. An IRC bot simply replies on commands. So now I have a list of static strings e.g.; `!weather`, `!lastseen` and the likes in my `Main.java` file.

For each command I add I create a new static string and I compare each incoming message if it starts with any of the defined commands.

**Pseudocode**

```
Receive message `m`
  if m matches !x
   -> do handleX()
  if m matches !y
   -> do handleY()
```

This is basicly a very large if test.

What I would like to do is create some sort of skeleton class that perhaps implements an interface and defines on which command it should act and a body that defines the code it should execute. Something I'm thinking of is shown below:

```
public class XkcdHandler implements CommandHandlerInterface
{
    public String getCommand()
    {
        return "!xkcd";
    }

    public void HandleCommand(String[] args, Channel ircChannel)
    {
        // Get XKCD..
        ircChannel.send("The XKCD for today is ..");
    }
}
```

With such a class I could simply add a new class and be done with it. Now I have to add the command, add the if test in the list, and add the method to the Main.java class. It is just not a nice example of software architecture.

Is there a way that I could create something that automatically loads these classes (or instances of those classes), and then just call something like `invokeMatchingCommand()`? This code could then iterate a list of loaded commands and invoke `HandleCommand` on the matching instance.

**Update**
With the answer of BalckEye in mind I figured I could load all classes that are found in a package (i.e., `Modules`), instantiate them and store them in a list. This way I could handle each message as shown in his answer (i.e., iterate the list and execute the class method for each matching command).

However, it seems, according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898175/is-possible-iterate-over-all-classes-inside-a-package-with-reflection), that it's not really viable to do. At this point I'm having a look at classloaders, perhaps that would be a viable solution.

Comment: Honestly, I get that you want to do this dynamically, but it is quite a hassle to do that. When you use user4335475's method, it'd be simple and clean. Plus, it is more API style :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways I think. You can just use a Map with the command as the key and an interface which executes your code as the value. Something like this:

```
Map<String, CommandInterface> commands = new ....
```

and then use the map like this:

```
CommandInterface cmd = commands.get(command);
if(cmd != null) {
    cmd.execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the static block, for instance:

```
class main {
     private static List<CommandHandlerInterface> modules = new ArrayList<...>();

    static { // gets called when a static member gets accessed for the first time (once per class)
         modules.add(new WeatherCommand());
         // etc.
    }

   // method here which iterates over modules and checks
}
```